# What is the benefit of defining Angular app?

Tags: angularjs

In some AngularJS tutorials, angular app is defined as:

```
myApp = angular.module("myApp",[]);
```

But we can also do without it. The only difference I can see is when we define controller, we can't use idiom:

```
myApp.controller("myCtrl",function(){ })
```

but has to use

```
function myCtrl (){}
```

Is there any other benefits of defining myApp explicitly, given that I will only create a single app for my site? If I don't define myApp, then where my modules are attached to?

If there is, how I can recreate myApp in testing with Jasmin?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can define controllers in (at least) 3 ways:

1. Define the controller as a global *var* (stored on the `window` object)

   ```
   function Ctrl() {}
   ```

   which is the same as doing:

   ```
   window.Ctrl = function () {}
   ```
2. Create a module and use the returned instance to create new controllers:

   ```
   var app = angular.module('app', []);
   app.controller('Ctrl', function() {});
   ```
3. Create the controllers directly on the module without storing any references (the same as `2` but without using vars):

   ```
   angular.module('app', []);
   angular.module('app').controller('Ctrl', function() {});
   ```

From Angular's point of view, they all do the same, you can even mix them together and they will work. The only difference is that option `1` uses global vars while in options `2` and `3` the controllers are stored inside an Angular's private object.

Answer (score 4):

I understand where you're coming from since the explanation for bootstrapping your Angular is all over the place. Having been playing with Angular only for a month (I'll share what I know anyways), I've seen how you have it defined above. I was also in the same scenario where I only have to define `myApp` once and not have multiple ones.

As an alternative, you can do something like this below. You'll notice that the Angular `app` and the `controller` doesn't have to live by the same `namespace`. I think that is more for readability and organization than anything.

**JS:**

```
window.app = {};
/** Bootstrap on document load and define the document along with 
      optional modules as I have below.
*/
angular.element(document).ready(function () {
    app.ang = angular.bootstrap(document, ['ngResource', 'ngSanitize']);

    // OR simply, works similarly.
    // angular.bootstrap(document, []);

});

/** Define Angular Controller */
app.myController= function ($scope, $resource, $timeout) {

};
```

**HTML:**

```
<div role="main" ng-controller="app.myController"></div>
```

Answer (score -3):

you have to define the app with angular.module anyway. myApp.controller and function myCtrl are the same..

Comment: Hi Gal, please correct me if I am wrong, but I don't think you need to define the app in order to define module. You can just use `angular.module('myModule,[])`. See, for example, http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_11

Comment: you have to create a module with your app name, otherwise ng-app will give you an error.

Comment: @GalBen-Haim, not necessarily. See my answer without the `ng-app` defined.