# How to connect ng-app using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I wrote out the last example on the angular website (angularjs.org/#create-components), but I'm not able to get the desired output.

Here is my code:

> [index.html](http://pastebin.com/2NQepn9M), [components.js](http://pastebin.com/QyYQcJw6),
>
> and app.js is at pastebin.com/XDpSkHBb (but StackOverflow doesn't let
>   me use more than 2 links)

I think the error is with `<html ng-app="app">`

because when I replace it with `<html ng-app>`

the `Date: {{ '2012-04-01' | date:'fullDate' }}`

are replaced with `Date: Sunday, April 1, 2012`

however, that means I'm no longer accessing the ng-app...

any thoughts on how I can fix this?

Comment: Im on my phone, but you need a statement such as `var app = angular.module ("app", [])`

Comment: It looks like `angular.module('app', ['components'])` works as a substitute. See:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14837359/what-is-the-benefit-of-defining-angular-app

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In app.js you have a period at the end of this line which is causing an error:

```
few: '{} pivá'.
```

change it to a comma:

```
few: '{} pivá',
```

And everything runs cleanly.  Here's a [working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/UyNNy0xX866q8fILi40W?p=preview)

I highly recommend adding a debugger, like [Chrome Developer Tools](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/), to your repertoire.  It makes it really fast and easy to spot these issues that otherwise can be daunting.

In this case the developer tools console reported this error on your code:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token : app.js:16
```

So I looked up one line, to line 15, and there's the issue:

```
few: '{} pivá'.
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll make sure to get a debugger. Any idea how to get the information into tabs though?

Comment: Looks like on line 9 in components.js you want `var panes = $scope.panes = [];` instead of `var panes = $scope.pans = [];`   Plunker updated.